# When using onBlur mode, can I make an exception for a specific field to NOT run validaiton onBlur?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

In my scenario, when a particular field (Field A) is updated, I need to load details about other fields (Field B and Field C) using an API call. The results from that call will set Field B and Field C's values. I would like to suspend validation until after this API call completes and Field B and Field C have been fully updated. This would be helpful because my validation process includes a network validation call of the entire form. With the onBlur validation of Field A, the network validation returns errors for Field B and Field C. These errors disappear a moment later after the Field A details load call finishes, Field B and C are updated with the returned details, and validation is manually triggered.

My form is set to use [mode onBlur](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#mode) because for all other fields, validating with onBlur event is expected - so I would like Field A to be the exception.

I understand I could manually trigger validation using [register's onBlur](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register) event for each field that blur validation is expected, but the form is large and there is only one onBlur exception.

Setting [register's onBlur](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register) event for Field A does NOT override the validation effect. That is - both validation and my custom Field A logic execute.